# off hover jquery using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that the hover method in query allows you to specify what happens when a user hovers and what happens when a user un-hovers. However, I am using .on() to handle the hover event because the content is dynamically created. How can I return it to its original state when the user un-hovers. Here is my code, I have tried .off() but it has not given the results I'm looking for:

```
$('tr').on('hover', 'td', function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1 )    
})
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
$('tr').off('hover', 'td', function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(500, .85 )         
})
```

thanks.

Comment: .hover are just shorthand functions .. .on("mouseover mouseleave") and .off("mouseover mouseleave") are actual events.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use `.on()`, the events to handler are "mouseenter" and "mouseleave". You can do it with a single call:

```
$('tr').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1); // or whatever
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 0.85); // or whatever
  }
}, 'td');
```

You can also do this with CSS, using the ":hover" pseudo-class.  That'll work even in older versions of IE, to some extent. You can animate the changes too.

Comment: Thanks, yes I do actually use CSS for the example above but I need to do things in hover other than style which is the reason I ask

Comment: @SamCreamer well then this should help.

Answer (score 11):

This is what you need

```
$('tr').on('mouseenter', 'td', function(){

    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1 )

}).on('mouseleave', 'td', function(){

    $(this).fadeTo(500, .85 )


})
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry about it. I did not remember the fact. Now I will :)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in **pure CSS** but here you go:

```
$('tr').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'td', function( e ){       
    $(this).fadeTo(500, e.type=="mouseenter" ? 1 : 0.85 );    
});
```

Using hover:

```
$('tr td').hover(function( e ){       
    $(this).fadeTo(500, e.type=="mouseenter" ? 1 : 0.85 );    
});
```

*Tip:*
`.on('hover'` will not bound direct references to the `mouseenter mouseleave` events separately like using the Method reference `$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)`, but just the `hover` event.

To resume:

```
$('tr').on('hover', 'td', function( e ){       
   // no separated "mouseenter" and no "mouseleave" e.type reference here :(
   // just "hover" event
});

$('tr').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'td', function( e ){       
   // e.type are defined :)
});

$('tr').on('mouseenter', 'td', function( e ){       
   // function only for 'mouseenter' event
}).on('mouseleave', 'td', function(){
   // function only for 'mouseleave' event
});

$('tr td').hover(function( e ){       
   // e.type "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" are in event reference :)
});

// $("tr td").hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)

$('tr td').hover(function(){       
   // Method default // e.type reference == "mouseenter" 
}, function(){
   // Method default // e.type reference == "mouseleave" 
});
```

Now it just depends if you need to delegate your events to elements using `.on()` (dynamically created elements) or is `.hover()` just suitable for your needs.

Regarding the `.off()` Method you can take a closer look at what it does: [here](http://api.jquery.com/off/)
Basically if at some point you want to remove any further event delegation to an element than you use .off():

```
$('#selector').on('click', 'button', function(){

  // Function callback:
  alert('I will alert only once cause of off()');
  $('#selector').off('click', 'button');

});
```

Comment: I do use css for this, but I have to do things on hover other than styling which is the purpose of my question

Comment: @SamCreamer I know that's what I thought.

Answer (score 3):

hover is not an event it is a shortcut for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event handlers

```
$('tr').on('mouseenter', 'td', function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1 )
}).on('mouseleave', 'td', function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(500, .85 )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.element').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(500, .85);
    }
);
```